# Change livewire datatable search placeholder text

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using laravel 8 and livewire . I want to change livewire datatable search placeholder text. How can I do it? Any Idea?

Livewire class

```html
class ShowGalleries extends LivewireDatatable
{
    public $model = Gallery::class;
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function columns()
    {
        return [
            NumberColumn::name('id')->label('ID')->sortBy('id'),
            Column::name('name')->label('Name'),
            Column::name('intro')->label('Intro'),
            DateColumn::name('created_at')->label('Creation Date'),
            Column::callback(['id'], function ($id) {
                return view('Pages.Gallery.components.actions', ['id' => $id]);
            })->label('Actions'),
        ];

    }
}
```

liviwire blade

```html
<div class="py-4">
            <livewire:show-galleries searchable="name, intro, created_at ,id" exportable hideable="select" />
        </div>
```

Comment: Please share relevant code.

Comment: @Digvijay updated with the code